# ps finds process, kill doesn't

Tags: fedora, kill, ps, dnf

**Specifications**

`[midas@localhost ~]$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 4.0.4-301.fc22.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu May 21 13:10:33 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

and

`[midas@localhost ~]$ cat /etc/issue
Fedora release 22 (Twenty Two)`

**Problem preface**

I was trying to install a new package through `dnf` on my Fedora 22. (Linux 4.0.4) When the package stopped downloading at 52% and the terminal window didn't show any more advancement.

I aborted the download and attempted to restart it using the same `dnf install [package name]` command.

I then received the following notification:
`Waiting for process with pid 2967 to finish.`

Turns out `dnf` was still running in the background:

`[midas@localhost ~]$ ps -A | grep 2967
 2967 ?        00:00:01 dnf`

**Problem**

I figured I could just `kill` the process, however:

`[midas@localhost ~]$ kill 2967
bash: kill: (2967) - No such process
[midas@localhost ~]$ sudo kill 2967
kill: sending signal to 2967 failed: No such process`

How come `ps` can list the process but `kill` can't find it?

I know a reboot will solve this (or a bit of patience even). But I'm just curious as to why there is such a difference between these 2 commands.

Comment: If you repeat the `ps`command, then the PID is still there?

Comment: @Jan, yes, right after the kill command it was.
After a while (while documenting for Stackexchange) the dnf started downloading the package and the ps entry with pid 2967 dissapeared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The listed process was probably already a zombie process, which you cannot kill.
Its live-time is depending on its parent process.

If you add the `u` flag to the call of `ps`, it displays
also the `STAT` column which is `Z` for zombie processes.

See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944886/how-to-kill-zombie-process
for more details.